# rainbowtext() function and y axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hey I'm using rainbow text function, which can be found in [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html)
in order to make y axis label have colors that match closest colors of the conosle names on y axis.
So currently I've came up with this code:

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(5,6)) #used to take care of the size
sns.barplot(x=gbyplat,y=gbyplat.index, palette='husl') #creating barplot
ax.set_ylabel('Publisher', color='deepskyblue', size=15, alpha=0.8) #setting labels
ax.set_xlabel('Number of titles published', color='slateblue', size=15, alpha=0.7)
ax.set_title('Titles per platform ranking', color='deeppink', size=17, alpha=0.6)
ax.set_xlim(0,2350) #setting limit for the plot
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, max(gbyplat), 250)) #ticks frequency
ax.annotate('newest', size=12, xy=(390, 13), xytext=(700, 13.3),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="fancy")) #annotations on plot
ax.annotate('max', size=9, xy=(2230,0.3), bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w", alpha=0.5))
ax.plot(2161,0, 'o', color='cyan') #creating the cricle highlight for PS2 max 

p = sns.color_palette("husl", len(gbyplat))
for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_color(p[i])
rainbow_text(0,5, "Pub lis her".split(),
             [p[10],p[11],p[12]],
             size=10)
```

However, the issue is that I have to manually set coordinates for newly produced 'Publisher' label. According to the function code i can pass ax argument which would automatically fit the label to the y axis (if I understood correctly). So how can I do that? And second question, is there a way to access ylabel coordinates (of the current y axis label 'Publisher')?
Thanks

[image: the plot]

Comment: No, you misunderstood what `ax` does. It simply selects the axes to which the text is added, which might be useful if you have more then one axes. However here you only have one axes and so you can leave it as `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can set the text at the position where the ylabel would normally reside by first drawing the ylabel, obtaining its coordinates and then setting it to an empty string. One can then adapt the [example rainbow text](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html) function to use the obtained coordinates.

It will still be very tricky to select the colors and coordinates such that the text will have exactly the color of the bars next to it. This probably involves a lot a trial and error.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
import seaborn as sns

l =list("ABCDEFGHIJK")
x = np.arange(1,len(l)+1)[::-1]
f, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4.5))
sns.barplot(x=x,y=l, palette='husl', ax=ax)

plt.xlabel('Number of titles published', color='slateblue', size=15, alpha=0.7)

p = sns.color_palette("husl", len(l))
for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_color(p[i])


def rainbow_text(x, y, strings, colors, ax=None, **kw):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    canvas = ax.figure.canvas

    lab = ax.set_ylabel("".join(strings))
    canvas.draw()
    labex = lab.get_window_extent()
    t = ax.transAxes
    labex_data = t.inverted().transform((labex.x0, labex.y0- labex.height/2.))
    ax.set_ylabel("")

    for s, c in zip(strings, colors):
        text = ax.text(labex_data[0]+x, labex_data[1]+y, s, color=c, transform=t,
                       rotation=90, va='bottom', ha='center', **kw)
        text.draw(canvas.get_renderer())
        ex = text.get_window_extent()
        t = transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, y=ex.height, units='dots')

rainbow_text(0, 0.06, ["Pub", "lish", "er"],[p[6], p[5],p[4]],size=15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: all right, so how do you obtain ylabel coordinates?

Comment: Do you mean, how to get the `0.06` in the example? That is just by trial and error; starting at `y=0` and then adapting it such that the plot looks ok. It will depend on the figure size as well, so for a different figuresize, one may need to choose a different value for y.

Comment: ah so there is no method or function for getting ylabel coords?

Comment: The method to find out the coordinates of the ylabel is built into my version of `rainbow_text` above. But the ylabel position is independent of the bar position, so in order to align the ylabel with the bar, its position can be slightly shifted compared to its original position using the `y` argument to the function. Just put y=0 there and see in how far it changes.

Comment: ah okay i get it now, so you retrive y label coords into labex_data and then use its coords and add them into x and y manually set (which can be 0 or around 0 right?)

Comment: Yes,  `labex` are the coordinates of the ylabel in the display coordinate system. `labex_data` are the coordinates in the axes coordinate system - shifted by half the label height. therefore `x` and `y` which you manually put in are in axes coordinates, ranging from 0 to 1. Since we only want to shift the label slightly, values around 0 make sense.

Comment: do you recommend any source where i can read more about the display coordinate system?

Comment: Start with the [transformation tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html).